# Get the last element of each sub-array of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I know that for an array it can be used `last` function of underscore, so in the case of this array it would be:

```
myArray = [32, 1, 8, 31]; 
lastElement = _.last(myArray);
```

The problem is when there is a matrix like this:

```
myArray = [[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]];
```

and the wanted result is

```
lastElement = [5, 77, 2];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `_.last(_.zip(...myArray))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) :

```js
var myArray = [[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]]; 

var res = Array.from(myArray, x => x[x.length - 1]);

console.log(res);
```

Another possibility not already answered here would be [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

```js
var myArray = [[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]]; 

var res = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr[curr.length - 1]),[]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and `slice` (Won't mutate the original array)

```
[[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]].map( s => s.slice(-1)[0] );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
var lastElement = myArray.map(_.last);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastElement = myArray.map((x) => {
   return _.last(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use ES6 `map`

```js
let myArray = [[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]]; 
let result = myArray.map(v => v[ v.length - 1] );

console.log(result );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. Iterate over the array using map and extract last element.

No need of any library.

```js
let myArray = [[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]]; 
let output = [];

output = myArray.map(m => m[m.length - 1] )

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This is a bad implementation of `.map`. Please check other answers

Comment: Why is this a bad implementation? Any reference you have for your statement?

Comment: I don't have any reference as of now but I'll try to explain. `.map` is used to get some mutated/parsed value of every item. It returns `n` items but with specific value. `.forEach` will loop over and process values but will not return anything. So if you use `.map` but do not return value or do not respect/accept returned value, its essentially same as `.forEach`. All array functions are meant for a reason. Yes you can achieve same task from all methods but you should use them for intended purpose, else you are killing their essence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.map` to transorm each subarray to the last element in it. You can get those last elements with `array.prototype.pop` or `arr[arr.length - 1]` if you don't want to mutate `myArray`:

```js
var myArray = [[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]]; 
var lastElements = myArray.map(arr => arr.pop());
console.log(lastElements);
```

Comment: `.pop()` will mutate array. Better use `.slice().pop()` or `arr[arr.length - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps loop through them with a for loop.

```
lastElement = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
    lastElement.push(_.last(myArray[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code:-

```js
var myArray = [[1, 3, 5], [55, 66, 77], [0, 1, 2]];
lastElement = _.map(myArray, _.last);
console.log(lastElement)
// **Result is lastElement = [5, 77, 2];**
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added lodash's CDN link and wrapped code in snippet(`<>` icon in editor). if you do not need the edit, please revert the changes.