# Get the last non-null element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having an array like this

```
myArray = ["test", 32.5, 11.3, 0.65, 533.2, null, 423.2, null, null];
```

is there a way to get the last non-null element?

In this case it should be `423.2`.

Comment: The "problems"
 you keep asking about (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190521/get-the-last-element-of-each-sub-array-of-an-array) require no more than one minute of thought and no more than one line of code. Are they really worth wasting space on SO servers?

Comment: And why you're now adding lodash/underscore to the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191915/return-an-array-using-arrow-functions)?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way of doing this is to filter out the `null` items using `.filter`, and then get the last element using `.slice`:

```
lastNonNull = myArray.filter(x => x != null).slice(-1)[0]
console.log(lastNonNull) // 432.2
```

To break this down a bit:

```
myArray
    .filter(x => x != null)    // returns ["test", 32.5, 11.3, 0.65, 533.2, 423.2]
    .slice(-1)                 // returns [423.2]
    [0]                        // returns 423.2
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way is `Array#reduce()`:

```js
var myArray = ["test", 32.5, 11.3, 0.65, 533.2, null, 423.2, null, null];
var last = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => curr ? curr : acc);
console.log(last);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `reverse` and `find`

```
["test", 32.5, 11.3, 0.65, 533.2, null, 423.2, null, null].reverse().find( s => s != null )
```

Or just one `reduceRight`

```
var arr = ["test", 32.5, 11.3, 0.65, 533.2, null, 423.2, null, null]
arr.reduceRight( (a,c) => ( c != null && a == null ? c : a) , null)
```

Comment: This is awesome and really concise, but it wouldn't work if the list contained a 'falsey' item, e.g. `0` or `""`.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen Check now

Comment: That's better; upvoted. Much more concise than my solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to filter the non null elements and use `pop` to get the last element.

```js
let myArray = ["test", 32.5, 11.3, 0.65, 533.2, null, 423.2, null, null];
let result = myArray.filter( v => v !== null ).pop();
  
console.log( result );
```