# return last non-null element of each sub-array of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having a bi-dimensional array like this

```
anArray = [[1, 2, 3], [null, 4, null, null], [1, 0, null, 5, null]];
```

my goal is to get as result a new array containing last element of each of the sub-arrays but also to be non-null. In this case: `[3, 4, 5]`

For getting the last element of each I used:

`anArray.map(a => a.slice(-1)[0]);` - it gets the last element of each sub-array.

For getting the last non-null element of an array it works using this:

```
_.findLast([1, null, 2, null], (el) => el !==null);
```

It works for a simple array but I don't know how to use it for a bi-dimensional array. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello Samurai Jack. Why not simple combine the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190521/get-the-last-element-of-each-sub-array-of-an-array) with one of the answer from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190873/get-the-last-non-null-element-of-an-array#comment85388895_49190873) questions or the comment from [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191915/return-an-array-using-arrow-functions)?

Comment: you may continue to use your underscorejs func:  **anArray.map((a) => a[_.findLastIndex(a, (el) => el !== null)])**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pop the last element for mapping.

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3], [null, 4, null, null], [1, 0, null, 5, null]];
    result = array.map(o => o.filter(n => n != null).pop());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

`.map()` will go through your initial array

`.filter()` will filter out the `null` values from your sub-arrays

`.slice()` will select the last element from each filtered sub-array

```js
var anArray = [[1, 2, 3], [null, 4, null, null], [1, 0, null, 5, null]];

var res = anArray.map(o => o.filter(n => n != null).slice(-1)[0]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You might be best using `slice` not `splice` or you will mutate the original array..

Comment: @Keith Corrected it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `reduceRight` (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49190934/1984039))

```
var anArray = [[1, 2, 3], [null, 4, null, null], [1, 0, null, 5, null]];
anArray.map( arr => arr.reduceRight( (a,c) => ( c != null && a == null ? c : a) , null))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `concat` with spread syntax and then `map` and `filter` methods to remove `null`.

```js
const anArray = [[1, 2, 3], [null, 4, null, null], [1, 0, null, 5, null]];

const result = [].concat(...anArray.map(e => e.filter(Boolean).slice(-1)))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in addition to `_.findLast`:

```
anArray.map(a => _.findLast(a, el => el !== null));
```

Working example:

```js
let anArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [null, 4, null, null],
  [1, 0, null, 5, null]
];

let result = anArray.map(a => _.findLast(a, el => el !== null));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

#### Idea:

- Use map to return value for every sub-array.
- Use while to loop backwards and get first not-null value.

**Note:** `while` because, most of the looping mechanism would loop over all values. To break at first match, and to reduce number of iterations, I prefer this.

```js
var anArray = [ [1, 2, 3], [null, 4, null, null], [1, 0, null, 5, null] ];
var result = anArray.map((subArray) => {
  var i = subArray.length - 1;
  while (i > 0) {
    if (subArray[i] !== null) {
      return subArray[i];
    }
    i--;
  }
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var anArray = [[1, 2, 3], [null, 4, null, null], [1, 0, null, 5, null]];
var anArray = anArray.map(function(arr){
    return findLastTruthyElement(arr);
});
console.log(anArray);
function findLastTruthyElement(arr){
    if(!Array.isArray(arr)){
        throw 'passed element is not array';
        return undefined;
    }
    arr = arr.filter(function(item){
        if(item) return true;
        else return false;
    });
    return arr[arr.length-1];
}
```